# How can I change the value of the second array after sorting the first one?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I just joined this website :)
I am a beginner and I had a problem. I have two arrays a [n] and b[n].
for example :

```
n = 3
3 10
6 5
2 30
```

The first column is array a and the second is array b. I sort array b but I need array a [i] to be for array b[i] after sorting . what can I do ?
I mean :
b = 30, 10, 5 (after sorting)
now a[0] = 3 and b [0] = 30 but I want it to be like this : a[0] = 2 b[0] = 30
I hope you could understand it
Thanks In advance :)

I need array a to be relevant to array b
please help me

Comment: What did you try so far? Looks like homework. We're willing to help you but at least you should try

Comment: I will type my explanation now : the problem : someone wants to do some work but he has just s hours empty to do them. There are n tasks that each of them takes a specific time from him and also he earns money by doing them. He wants to earn the highest money.   My solution : We have to sort the money from greatest tosmallest and I did it. After that we have to see whether the time of each isn't higher than the time left or not. But I don't know how to keep the time array for the money array after sorting??

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/J6RC4bBTwf/

Comment: This is my code , The problem that I have is written in the comment in the for loop

Comment: Code should go in question, not external link.  Anyway, this is duplicate.  One of many duplicates.  See the linked Q&A regarding how to sort two arrays that are related.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It was my first day that I joined this website and I am also young so I didn't know that I can put my code there. Thanks anyway :)